# Ajax serialized form with values not getting passed correctly to my controller's action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I set up a javascript alert to confirm that my form.serialize is working correctly, and it is.  The issue is that my controller action is not associating any of the data from the form to the model.

**Javascript alert with the passed form values**

The first value in this alert is `StartDate` with a value of `02/25/2020`, but in the screenshot of the controller below it is not binded to the dailyReport object's StartDate value.

[image: alert]

**Screenshot of the controller and passed object**

[image: VS screenshot]

**Ajax**

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit').on('click', function (evt) {
        alert($('#reportForm').serialize());
        evt.preventDefault();
        //Ajax form post
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#reportForm').serialize(),
            url: '@Url.Action("Daily","Reports")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    alert("Data Success");
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    //Toggle the error modal and display error messages
                    $('#errorsModal').modal('toggle');
                    //Add <br> tags when there is a linebreak in the string.  This will add the line breaks into the HTML.
                    $('#errorsModal .modal-body p').html(data.message.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>'));
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Daily(Daily dailyReport)
{
    var dr = new ReportDaily();
    var rc = new ReportDailyCriteria();
    dr.Preview(rc, IntPtr.Zero, out Notification notification);
    if (notification.HasErrors)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            success = false,
            message = notification.GetConcatenatedErrorMessage(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)
        });
    }

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Comment: what about: data: JSON.stringify($('#reportForm').serialize())

Comment: @Adlorem unfortunately, that didn't work.I also tried `JSON.stringify({ dailyReport: $("#reportForm").serialize() })`. dailyReport is the name of my object parameter.

Comment: please show your controller action

Comment: @Adlorem added the controller action

Comment: Thank you. What about just changing: contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' to: dataType: 'html', because actually you are not passing json in post method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from using `'application/json; charset=utf-8'` to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' fixed the issue.`